# Expression Simplification using SymPy trigsymp

Tags: python, sympy, simplify, simplification

Why does the following simple example not return 1?

```
from sympy import *

r, theta, phi = symbols('r, theta, phi')
pprint(trigsimp(cos(phi)**2 * sin(theta)**2+sin(phi)**2 * sin(theta)**2  
+ cos(theta)**2))
```

Instead, I get

```
   2       2         2       2         2         2   
sin (φ)⋅sin (θ) - cos (φ)⋅cos (θ) + cos (φ) + cos (θ)
```

the same for `simplify()`.

Comment: FWIW, I get 1 from your code in sympy 0.7.6.1.

Comment: I have 0.7.1, so this really might be the simple problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be only a version issue, in sympy 0.7.6.1 it works fine